# What is the least intrusive way to display WPF tooltip on focus?

Tags: wpf, tooltip

What is the minimum number of steps required to display a tooltip when the following control gets focus?

```
<TextBox ToolTip="Hello there!" ... />
```

I tried the following in GotFocus

```
    private void ..._GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        var tooltip = element.ToolTip;
        if (!(tooltip is ToolTip)) {
            tooltip = new ToolTip { Content = tooltip };
            element.ToolTip = tooltip;
        }

        ((ToolTip)tooltip).IsOpen = true;
    }
```

However, it seems to ignore the `ToolTipService.Placement` for this control and `SystemParameters.ToolTipPopupAnimationKey` set up level higher.

How can I make it work and honor all settings that generally work for tooltips (except the timing, obviously)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a Windows machine to test, but I would have thought:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox">
    <TextBox.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip IsOpen="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, ElementName=textBox}">
            Whatever
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: `ToolTipService.IsOpen` unfortunately does not have an available setter (as compared to `ToolTip.IsOpen`).

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't answer questions when I'm uncertain and can't test :) How about my revision - does that help?

Comment: This would work, yes, and this is my current solution, however I really do not want to rewrite the TetBox itself. I want to make it into an attached property which will not require user to write tooltip as `ToolTip`. After all, `ToolTipService` does not.

Comment: I've tried this solution, but I can't seem to Bind to anything outside of the tooltip.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd build an IsKeyboardFocused binding in the attached property, like this:

```
 public class ShowOnFocusTooltip : DependencyObject
 {
   public object GetToolTip(...
   public void SetToolTip(...
   public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolTipProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(..., new PropertyMetadata
   {
     PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) =>
     {
       ToolTipService.SetToolTip(obj,
         e.NewValue==null ? null :
         BuildToolTip(obj, e.NewValue));
     }
   });

   private object BuildToolTip(DependencyObject control, object content)
   {
     var tooltip = content is ToolTip ? (ToolTip)content : new ToolTip { Content = content };
     tooltip.SetBinding(ToolTip.IsOpenProperty,
       new Binding("IsKeyboardFocusWithin") { Source = control });
     return tooltip;
   }
```

Comment: That's very similar to my original solution. I haven't tried it yet, but `new Tooltip` seem to imply the same problem: ignored `ToolTipService.Placement` and `SystemParameters.ToolTipPopupAnimationKey`. I can copy the first one, but I really want to just get the ToolTip that service uses, since it will be future-proof in terms of properties and styles.

Comment: The "new Tooltip" code is for convenience when you don't want to set any of those properties.  If you do, your XAML can give an explicit ToolTipPlacement etc:  `<TextBox><my:ShowOnFocusTooltip.Tooltip><ToolTip Placement="..." ... /></my:ShowOnFocusTooltip.Tooltip></TextBox>`

Comment: The problem is, for the user of the attached property, it is not obvious that `ToolTipService.Placement` does not work anymore and that he should use explicit `ToolTip` with `Placement` instead. Of course, I can throw an exception, but this would violate the rule of least surprise. And the whole question is about preserving original way of configuring tooltips.